# ASP.NET Web API resource not found error

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I have added a Api Controller in my asp.net mvc5 web project, along with other controllers...i am contstantly getting resource not found error. please point out mistakes i might be making...

following is my Register method for WebApi routes

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

here is the Global.asax.cs

```
 protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        //GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    }
```

here is my Api controller class

```
public class SearchController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<string> GetSearch()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

"http://sukhdev.com/api/search" is the url scheme i use to call web api, but it persistenly "The resource cannot be found."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why did you commented //GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);



    }
```

Comment: GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register) will register your routes

Comment: it is done by   WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

Comment: no, but uncommenting GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register) also not working

Comment: I've just checked order is important move GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register); before RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

Comment: yups..i also came to this, i minutely observed the "Newly Created" MVC and Web API project by Visual Studio and observed the order in which the routes are regiesterd :) feeling Happy after hours :)